# Debian 8 - Resolve DNS in multiple nameservers

Tags: debian, dns

I've recently installed Debian 8 (Jessie) and I'm having trouble with DNS resolving in a particular network configuration: I must connect to 2 different networks (1) ethernet and (2) wireless.

Each network has it's own DNS servers and here lies the problem. When the system is asked to resolve a URL, it only uses the first DNS server (I have 3, and some are intranet-specific, while other are internet-specific).

Is there a configuration to force DNS resolution on all 3 servers (or resolve in cascade - e.g. if the first fails, try the second, etc..) ?

Comment: It's possible, but requires you to setup BIND as a local DNS forwarder on your machine. [Here](http://www.unix.com/ip-networking/133552-howto-linux-multihomed-dns-client.html) is a how-to. Though it's from 2009 it should still be valid to date.

Comment: Thank you Nephente, it that was helpful but since I'm using a laptop it doesn't seem a flexible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might like to try **dnsmasq**, which is a small caching DNS proxy that is simple to set up and has an option:

> --all-servers
>   forces dnsmasq to send all queries to all available servers. The reply
>   from the server which answers first will be returned to the original
>   requester.

Amongst other things you add to the start of /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

followed by your real nameservers, so requests go first to dnsmasq.
See [debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/HowTo/dnsmasq).
This also has the advantage of reducing network traffic, as results
are cached.

Comment: Thanks I'm going to give this a try and I'll update the thread with the results

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem. For reference, I followed this instructions to get it working on Debian 8: [http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37264/how-to-get-networkmanager-to-configure-domain-specific-name-servers-with-openres]